# Detect string in a different dataframe, return value from column in R

Tags: r, string

In a dataframe I have a character column (one word) where each word can appear multiple times

```
word = c(
   "OMEPRAZOL",
   "PARACETAMOL",
   "HIDROFEROL",
   "ENALAPRIL",
   "PARACETAMOL",
   "NOISE"
)
```

In a different dataframe I have a column with strings and another with an associated ID code:

```
string_code = data.frame(
   string = c(
   "OMEPRAZOL XXXX",
   "OMEPRAZOL YYYY",
   "PARACETAMOL/A XXXX",
   "PARACETAMOL/B YYYY",
   "HIDROFEROL XXXX",
   "ENALAPRIL XXXX",
   "ENALAPRIL YYYY"),
   code = c(
   "11",
   "11",
   "22",
   "22",
   "33",
   "44",
   "44")
)
```

I would like look up for each element of `word` in `string_code$string` and when there is a match get in return the associated ID from `string_code$code` (only the first match since there might be multiple ones, and the ID is the same anyway) - NA if no match.

```
word_code = data.frame(
   word = c(
   "OMEPRAZOL",
   "PARACETAMOL",
   "HIDROFEROL",
   "ENALAPRIL",
   "PARACETAMOL",
   "NOISE"),
   code = c(
   "11",
   "22",
   "33",
   "44",
   "22",
   "NA")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a potential application for `regex_full_join()` from the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Try

```
    fuzzyjoin::regex_full_join(string_code, word) %>% select(-1) %>% distinct
```

to obtain

```
>   fuzzyjoin::regex_full_join(string_code, word) %>% select(-1) %>% distinct
Joining by: "string"
  code    string.y
1   11   OMEPRAZOL
2   22 PARACETAMOL
3   33  HIDROFEROL
4   44   ENALAPRIL
5 <NA>       NOISE
```

Note that you need define `word` like so,

```
  word <- as.data.frame(word)
  colnames(word) <- "string"
```

Comment: thanks so much this seems to be working fine. But now i have another issue: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size X Gb"... I guess this is a different question, but now Im here... what would you recommend? Splitting the large `string_code` df? Or maybe just keeping the X first characters of `string_code$string`, where X = `max(nchar(word))`?

Comment: You could split the dataframe and apply the solution above to all parts. I wouldn't censor the dataframe. Due to its size you may not know precisely what you delete.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply do

```
word_code <- data.frame(word=word, code=sapply(word, function(w){string_code$code[grep(w, string_code$string)[1]]}))
```